# Log4j2 synchronous logging

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, synchronous

How can I have both synchronous as well as asynchronous logging using `log4j2`.

Any sample implementation if available will help a lot.

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration you can have a mixture of `<AsyncLogger>` and `<Logger>` elements. In addition you can have either `<AsyncRoot>` or `<Root>`.